# Hadoop distcp wrong path still copies - where did data go?

Tags: hadoop, distcp

I was running `hadoop distcp` to copy a whole directory (500GB+) from `/path/to/source` to `/path/to/destination`. However, instead of running

```
$ hadoop distcp /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

I did the following in mistake

```
$ hadoop distcp /path/to/source path/to/destination
```

The operation completed like a normal distcp copy, with `mapreduce` taking some time to run, and of course I did not get my data in `/path/to/destination`. It was also not in `/path/to/source/path/to/destination`, or other relative paths I could think of.

Where did the data go? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't go anywhere if the destination path is not correct it stays in the source location

Comment: Thanks, you must be correct because the count showed no extra space taken. I wonder what all the map reduce time taken was spent doing.